# WordPress 4.8.2 не работает is_front_page()

Tags: php, wordpress

Не работает функция `is_front_page()`. Установлен *WordPress 4.8.2*.
В параметрах чтения выбрана статическая страница (`id = 26`),
пробовал `is_page(26)`, также не работает.

```
if (is_front_page()) {
    //код
}
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Где "не работает"?

Comment: в functions.php
Мне нужно изменить хеадер на главной странице, но не могу сделать даже обычный вывод
if (is_front_page()) {
    echo "TEST";
}

Comment: В вопросе напиши что где и как делаешь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код functions.php выполняется до формирования основного цикла WordPress, поэтому вызов is_front_page(), is_page(), is_home() и всего остального, связанного с основным циклом, обречен на провал.

Для модификации заголовка используйте соответствующий хук WordPress в functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'action_wp_head' );
function action_wp_head(){
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        // вывести что-то в заголовок
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если на главной отображаются последние записи, то нужно использовать is_home().
Если в качестве главной установлена статическая страница, то тогда is_home() не будет работать и используем is_front_page().

Comment: В качестве главной установлена статическая страница и is_front_page() не работает

Comment: Попробуйте так <?php wp_reset_query(); if (is_front_page() || is_home()) { echo 'home'; } ?>

Comment: Без результатов